# Who can use this?

Tags: search

In reference to the patent: [US6506148](https://www.google.com/patents/US6506148)

Who has rights to this patent?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in the USA, neither disclosure of assignment of ownership nor licensing of rights - exclusive or otherwise - are mandatory.  Thus we are largely unable to answer your question definitively, as [the inventor](https://www.lens.org/lens/search?inventor=LOOS%20HENDRICUS%20G) is still - according to the USPTO - the owner of record.  The FAQ about how to find out what *is* known and how to proceed is [here](http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/transferring-ownership-assignments-faqs).

However, this patent and others by Loos [have been the subject of extensive speculation](http://www.topsecretwriters.com/2015/11/the-mysterious-hendricus-loos-and-his-nervous-system-manipulation-devices/), including the expected conspiracy theories.